# Output of non-inverting op-amp amplifier less than expected

Tags: voltage, operational-amplifier

[image]

Why does this result in a 15 V output voltage?

I played a little with different values such as 0.2 V for input, 10k ground resistor and feedback resistor of 80k and the formulas for voltage gain:

$$ V_{gain} = \frac {R_f}{R_{ground} +1 } $$

and

$$ V_o = gain \times V_{in} $$

and it worked but not with image settings.

Comment: Hi! Please write a title that really describes your question.

Comment: What voltage you expect and why?

Comment: Surprising formula.....have never seen something like this...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> *Why does this result in a 15V output voltage?*

More than likely the model of the op-amp you chose has built-in output voltage limiting to +/- 15 volts hence, with a gain of 1 + 50/5 (=11) and an input of +3 volts, it cannot produce a realizable output voltage of 33 volts and hits the built-in end-stops of +15 volts.